# Session Data Not Saving to Database in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to use CDbHttpSession in Yii to store the session data into a database. However, Yii doesn't seem to store the information, just update the id.
Here is a full application log:

```
03:23:21.016446 trace   system.db.CDbCommand    
Querying SQL: SELECT *
FROM `YiiSession`
WHERE id=:id. Bound with :id='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7'
in /YIIPATH/protected/models/LoginForm.php (29)
in
/YIIPATH/protected/controllers/SiteController.php
(115)
in /YIIPATH/index.php (13)
03:23:21.016472 profile system.db.CDbCommand.query  
begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT *
FROM `YiiSession`
WHERE id=:id. Bound with :id='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7')
03:23:21.017136 profile system.db.CDbCommand.query  
end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT *
FROM `YiiSession`
WHERE id=:id. Bound with :id='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7')
03:23:21.017270 trace   system.db.CDbCommand    
Executing SQL: UPDATE `YiiSession` SET `id`=:id WHERE id=:oldID. Bound with
:oldID='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7', :id='26h85kqrvrecd67kdf4riahca5'
in /YIIPATH/protected/models/LoginForm.php (29)
in
/YIIPATH/protected/controllers/SiteController.php
(115)
in /YIIPATH/index.php (13)
03:23:21.017291 profile system.db.CDbCommand.execute    
begin:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(UPDATE `YiiSession` SET `id`=:id WHERE
id=:oldID. Bound with :oldID='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7',
:id='26h85kqrvrecd67kdf4riahca5')
03:23:21.017766 profile system.db.CDbCommand.execute    
end:system.db.CDbCommand.execute(UPDATE `YiiSession` SET `id`=:id WHERE
id=:oldID. Bound with :oldID='9m6bmlf12v4r9e7bleusv1rmp7',
:id='26h85kqrvrecd67kdf4riahca5')
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I've noticed that if you're using the database for session storage, you must set a duration under the user identity, otherwise it defaults to 0. In case anyone ever has this issue as well.